# Heroku - unable to add addons

Tags: git, heroku, cmd, add-on

I have deployed an app on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). I am finding it surprisingly hard to add addons to it.

For example I tried `heroku addons:upgrade logging:expanded` to expand the logging service. But I get the following error
`!    Could not connect to logging service`

I also couldn't get `heroku logs` command to work. It gave me `!    Could not connect to logging services`

And similarly for `heroku addons:add papertrail` the error being `Addon plan not found`

Am I missing something here? Am I supposed to configure anything before running these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context to:

> Could not connect to logging service!

Heroku services are sometimes down for maintenance or due to technical glitches. It's usually a temporary problem. To confirm, if this is the case, you can try visiting https://status.heroku.com/ at the time when you are experiencing such issues.

In context to:

> Addon plan not found

You syntax for adding the addon (`heroku addons:add papertrail`) looks fine.

However, heroku require your account to be verified before you can use addons. For account verification, you need to add your credit card information, EVEN IF you are using FREE addons. You can find more details [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification).